# Postfix rejects mails if policyd is not reachable

Tags: postfix, smtp, smtpd

I got a postfwd daemon running and it does a great job.

```
smtpd_recipient_restrictions =
      [...]
      check_policy_service inet:192.168.10.7:10040
```

But if this server (192.168.10.7) isn't reachable, postfix rejects all mails with server configuration errors (4**). I am looking for something like a timeout. A timeout which skips this check if the policyd isnt running. I searched the documentation a lot, but there is nothing related to my problem.

Any ideas?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could write your own proxy policyd daemon which will bypass all request to real policyd or will return OK to postfix if real policyd is not responding.

Answer (score 3):

Unless something has happened in the last 5 years, there doesn't seem to be a proper solution

http://www.mail-archive.com/policyd-weight-list@ek-muc.de/msg00362.html

Comment: Mh, okay. I should think about a separate layer between this services...